# Question about memory usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have the following method:

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)getTime:(float)lat :(float)lon {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictionary setObject:hour forKey:@"hour"];
    [dictionary setObject:minute forKey:@"minute"];
    [dictionary setObject:ampm forKey:@"ampm"];

    return dictionary;
}
```

A lot of the method is chopped off, so I think I need the pool for some other stuff in the method.  Here's my question.  I know that I need to release the following objects:

```
[dictionary release];
[pool release];
```

However, I can't release the dictionary before I return it, but as soon as I return it the rest of the method isn't performed.  What should I do?

Comment: Methods in Objective-C are *never* named `get*` unless they return multiple values by reference.   Nor do you see bare colons like that.  Name your method something like `timeForLatitude:longitude:`.

Comment: @bbum Thanks for the style suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always `autorelease` the dictionary, thereby ensuring it is kept in memory at least until `getTime::` returns. This conforms well to the memory paradigm on Cocoa, where a method which returns an object which it creates (but does not own), calls `autorelease` on it when it no longer needs it.

Of course, make sure to retain that dictionary in any code that receives it from `getTime::`.

Comment: +1 Make sure you release the pool before autoreleasing the dictionary, or the dictionary will be released with the pool, causing a really hard to find problem.

Comment: Hmm, got rid of the pool because I decided I didn't need it.  Now when I call `autorelease` it crashes my app.  Ah, memory causes me stress. :)

Comment: Probably because it is being released, yet your code still requires it somewhere. Are you missing a retain on the dictionary that is returned by getTime?